# Separate a string based on a second table

Tags: mysql, string

I've got a string (german telephonenumber) including the prefix in a string without any separation like this: `phone = 030123456`.

Since the prefix has no unique length it must be checked against another table including all prefix numbers.

How do I separate the string into the prefix and the number?

```
prefix = 030, number = 123456
```

Comment: show `another table including all prefix numbers` table with columns and sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Number, 
       coalesce(Prefix, 'Unrecognized') AS Prefix, 
       substr(Number, length(Prefix)+1) AS LocalPart,
       coalesce(Name, 'Unknown') AS Region
from Phone
left join Prefix on substr(Number, 1, length(Prefix)) = Prefix
```

[Sample fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90828/14).

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to insert the `number` in `localpart` if no matching prefix is found?

Comment: Just add a `coalesce` around it like `coalesce(...statement..., Number)` - what it does it return the first non-null parameter.

Comment: Never used the [coalesce function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) before, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  prefixes.prefix,
  SUBSTRING(phones.phone, LENGTH(prefixes.prefix)+1) number
FROM
  phones INNER JOIN prefixes
  ON phones.phone LIKE CONCAT(prefixes.prefix, '%')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1654/3).